# Remove string from a particular field using awk/sed

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, bioinformatics

I have a file (>80,000 lines) that looks likes this:

```
chr1    GTF2GFF chromosome  1   249213345   .   .   .   ID=chr1;Name=chr1
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    11874   14408   .   +   .   ID=DDX11L1;Note=unknown;Name=DDX11L1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    11874   12227   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    13221   14408   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    14362   29370   .   -   .   ID=WASH7P;Note=unknown;Name=WASH7P
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    14362   14829   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    14970   15038   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    15796   15947   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    16607   16765   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    16858   17055   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17233   17368   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17606   17742   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17915   18061   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    18268   18366   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    24738   24891   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    29321   29370   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    34611   36081   .   -   .   ID=FAM138A;Note=unknown;Name=FAM138A
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    34611   35174   .   -   .   Parent=NR_026818
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    35277   35481   .   -   .   Parent=NR_026818
```

and I want to extract only the rows that that contain "gene" in the 3rd field and re-arrange the 9th field to contain only the ID value (for example, DDX11L1). This is the desired output:

```
chr1    11874   14408   DDX11L1    .       +
chr1    14362   29370   WASH7P      .       -
chr1    34611   36081   FAM138A    .       -
```

Using awk I got the desired fields easily:

```
head -20 genes.gff3 | awk '$3=="gene" {print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $9"\t" $6 "\t" $7}'
chr1    11874   14408   ID=DDX11L1;Note=unknown;Name=DDX11L1    .       +
chr1    14362   29370   ID=WASH7P;Note=unknown;Name=WASH7P      .       -
chr1    34611   36081   ID=FAM138A;Note=unknown;Name=FAM138A    .       -
```

But I am struggling with getting the ID value. I've tried piping it to sed:

```
head -20 genes.gff3 | awk '$3=="gene" {print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $9"\t" $6 "\t" $7}' | sed 's/\(^.+\t\)ID=\(\w+\).+\(\t.+$\)/\1\2\3/g'
```

and also gsub

```
head -20 genes.gff3 | awk '$3=="gene" {gsub(/\(^.+\t\)ID=\(\w+\).+\(\t.+$\)/, "\1\2\3", $9); print $1 "\t" $4 "\t" $5 "\t" $9"\t" $6 "\t" $7}'
```

But the result is same as using awk alone. How can I extract the ID value? I feel that I am really close to a solution here.

Cheers.

Comment: I wrote a Bash function to solve this. I will paste it here if it is fine with you.

Comment: Please do @RanyAlbegWein

Comment: is ID always the first var=value? `awk '/gene/{sub(/;.*/,"");print}'`

Comment: Yes it is @Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`split`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_13) the field and use [`substr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_13) by:

```
split($9, a, ";")
print substr(a[1], 4)
```

*Awk indexes start at `1`.*

Another option could be to modify the input field separator (`FS`).
`FS` is space, " ", by default – which also has the special effect of [ignoring
leading and trailing spaces](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Splitting-Summary.html#Field-Splitting-Summary).

Also, instead of using `print $1, \t, ...` or the `printf` variant one could
set `OFS` to tab.

---

### Examples:

***Modifying FS:***

```
awk -F" +|;|=" '

$3 == "gene" {
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",
    $1, $4, $5, $10, $6, $7);
}
' data.file
```

---

***Using split:***

```
awk '
$3 == "gene" {
    split($9, a, ";")
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n",
    $1, $4, $5, substr(a[1], 3), $6, $7);
}
' data.file
```

---

***OFS and FS:***

[Output Field Separator](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html) (`OFS`) as tab, and alternative `FS` inside awk.
Also updated `FS` to include tab:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="[ \t]+|;|="
    OFS="\t"
}
$3 == "gene" {
    print $1, $4, $5, $10, $6, $7
}

' data.file
```

---

Also see *The Open Group* [Variables and Special Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03), [Examples](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_16).

[Gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) – it usually is noted when things are a gawk extension to awk.

Comment: Getting close but it results in: `chr1    11874   14408   .       .       +       ID=DDX11L1` and "ID" should also be removed.

Answer (score 6):

The field separator of the `split` function is a regular expression, so you can split on `=` OR `;`.  If you know that `$9` *begins* with "ID=", then

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $3 == "gene" {
        split($9, id, /[=;]/)
        print $1, $4, $5, id[2], $6, $7
    }
' genes.gff3
```

If "ID=" is not necessarily at the beginning of the field, then there's a little more work to do:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $3 == "gene" {
        id = ""
        len = split($9, f, /[=;]/)
        for (i=1; i<len; i++) {
            if (f[i] == "ID") {
                id = f[i+1]
                break
            }
        }
        print $1, $4, $5, id, $6, $7    
    }
' genes.gff3
```

Comment: Your answer also works, but I've decided to accept Sukminder's because the syntax is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Bash solution, as allowed me to publish, despite the explicit request asking to use `awk` and `sed`:

```
show_genes()
{
    local filename="$1"
    while read -ra larr; do
        if [[ ${larr[2]} = gene ]]; then
            larr[8]="${larr[8]%%;*}"
            larr[8]="${larr[8]#ID=}"
            printf '%s\n' "${larr[*]}"
        fi
    done < "$filename"
}
```

**Usage:** show_genes /path/to/some/file.txt

**Sample output:**

```
[rany$] cat data.txt
romosome  1   249213345   .   .   .   ID=chr1;Name=chr1
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    11874   14408   .   +   .   ID=DDX11L1;Note=unknown;Name=DDX11L1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    11874   12227   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    13221   14408   .   +   .   Parent=NR_046018_1
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    14362   29370   .   -   .   ID=WASH7P;Note=unknown;Name=WASH7P
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    14362   14829   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    14970   15038   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    15796   15947   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    16607   16765   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    16858   17055   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17233   17368   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17606   17742   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    17915   18061   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    18268   18366   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    24738   24891   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    29321   29370   .   -   .   Parent=NR_024540
chr1    GTF2GFF gene    34611   36081   .   -   .   ID=FAM138A;Note=unknown;Name=FAM138A
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    34611   35174   .   -   .   Parent=NR_026818
chr1    GTF2GFF exon    35277   35481   .   -   .   Parent=NR_026818
[rany$] show_genes data.txt
chr1 GTF2GFF gene 11874 14408 . + . DDX11L1
chr1 GTF2GFF gene 14362 29370 . - . WASH7P
chr1 GTF2GFF gene 34611 36081 . - . FAM138A
[rany$]
```

Comment: Cool thanks. Now I know that this could have also been done in bash.

Comment: @fridaymeetssunday You welcome

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick coffee break answer

```
perl -ne 's/\t.*?\tgene//            #remove \t F2 \t gene
      and s/\S*\tID=(.*?);.*/$1/     #remove \t Fn \t ID=.... keeping the id
      and print'  file
```